# Error: Duplicate declaration virtual defines user & group equal name

Tags: puppet, files

I need create a user with the name user1 & group user1.
I defined a virtual resource to create it. 
Inside a class1 I create the user:

```
 include '::class1::virtual_accounts'
  realize(class::User['user1'])
```

Inside class2, create the group:

```
 include '::class1::virtual_accounts'
  realize(class::Group['user1'])
```

Inside virtual_accounts:

```
class class1::virtual_accounts {
  @class::group { 'user1': }
  @class::user { 'user1': }
```

When execute appears the error:

```
Error: Duplicate declaration: Group[user1] is already declared in file /root/puppet/class/manifests/group.pp:23; cannot redeclare at /root/puppet/class/manifests/user.pp:95 on node arqopasr21.lacaixa.es
```

Inside user.pp & group.pp I have the definition for create user & groups.
It's possible the error has been generated because the virtual resource have the same name (user1) thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the declarations of resources must be unique. If you use virtual resources, declare them just once:

```
@user { 'name': ... }
```

There must be no other virtual or non-virtual declaration of the `User['name']` resource. You can *realize* or *collect* the resource as often as you wish.

```
User<| |>
User<| title == 'name' |>
realize(User['name'])
```

As a general remark, avoid naming a module **class** since `class` is a reserved word.